# How does proxying and caching affect analytics?

Tags: proxy, analytics

What is the effect of proxying and caching at the web server on analytics reports and figures?

I have an online resource that has recently been bogged down by traffic and I want to reduce dynamic generation by extensively using caching and proxying at the server level.

However I still want to have intact and sound analytics, especially of the kind of traffic we are receiving.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a javascript based analytics system such as Google Analytics they will not impact your analytics at all. However, if you are using a server based system, such as analyzing your log files, any proxied content will not show in your logs, rendering them very unreliable.